# Unable to install some PHP extensions (modules) in official Docker PHP Alpine image

Tags: php, docker, couchbase, php-extension, alpine-linux

I'm having problems with installation of Couchbase PHP extension (module) to official PHP 7.0 Alpine docker image.

I've managed to install and enable **XDebug** and **OPCache** extensions, but couldn't do that for **intl** and **Couchbase** extensions.

I've used PECL, Alpine packages and `docker-php-ext-*` commands, but all are giving me various kinds of error messages in the end. Like the following:

```
#RUN docker-php-ext-enable /usr/lib/php7/intl.so
# nm: /usr/lib/php7/intl.so: no symbols

#RUN cp /etc/php7/conf.d/00_intl.ini $PHP_CONFIG_SCAN_DIR/intl.ini
# PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so' - Error loading shared library /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
# not even with echo extension=/usr/lib/php7/intl.so > $PHP_CONFIG_SCAN_DIR/intl.ini

#COPY ./php/couchbase.ini $PHP_CONFIG_SCAN_DIR/couchbase.ini
# PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php7/couchbase.so' - Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/couchbase.so: php_log_err_with_severity: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0

#RUN docker-php-ext-enable /usr/lib/php7/couchbase.so
# nm: /usr/lib/php7/couchbase.so: no symbols
# PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php7/couchbase.so' - Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/couchbase.so: php_log_err_with_severity: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0

#RUN docker-php-ext-enable /usr/lib/php7/opcache.so
# PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php7/opcache.so' - Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/opcache.so: zend_vm_set_opcode_handler_ex: symbol not found in Unknown on line 0

#RUN docker-php-ext-enable /usr/lib/php7/modules/couchbase.so
# error:  does not exist
```

My Dockerfile with results of all the experiments is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/meridius/d91781e1eaf1f23b0643314d073d7c53).

Answer (score 0):

You can find installation instruction in the official documentation
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/php/start-using-sdk.html

Are you sure you have installed all dependencies? libcouchbase in particular. Your dockerfile has this section commented out.